# React read image url from link to server path

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an api that looks like this :

```
{
        "id": 9,
        "fullnames": "JOHN DOE",
        "email": "johndoe@gmail.com",
        "status": "Active",
        "directreport": null,
        "date_created": "2021-11-01T09:29:33.000+0000",
        "date_updated": "2022-03-22T12:42:50.000+0000",
        "view": true,
        "lineManager": 43,
        "accessLevel": "Level1",
        "lastLogIndate": "06-Apr-2022 13:08:06",
        "userPicture": "/var/www/html/media/strongnightstand.png",
    }
```

The userPicture is a a link to a directory in the server where all images are stored. I am trying to put the link as the image source but the image does not display. My build file is in `/var/www/html/stratex` while the images are in `/var/www/html/media` .
My code looks like this :

```
const [avatar, setAvatar] = useState("");

 useEffect(() => {
    if(myuser) {
      setName(myuser.fullnames);
      setEmail(myuser.email);
      setTeamId(myuser.team);
      setId(myuser.id);
      setAvatar(myuser.userPicture);
    }
    
 }, [myuser]);

<CardAvatar profile>
    { avatar == null || avatar == undefined || avatar === '' || avatar == "null" ? ( <img src={Avatar} alt="..." /> )
    : avatar ? ( <img src={avatar} alt="..." /> )
    : (<img src={Avatar} alt="..." /> )}

</CardAvatar>
```

Any advice/help on what im doing wrong will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Use a relative path. Something like `../media/strongnightstand.png` rather than a qualified-from-root path.

Comment: You could also try storing the images in your database and accessing it from there instead when u get the data from the API. (As an alternate)

Comment: @lakimapturn when i store them in the database the site is super slow